# Cheapest way to persist string for lambda job

Tags: aws-lambda

I need to permanently store a string between runs of a lambda function.  The function will never overlap runs, it will pull the string at the beginning and update the stored version at the end of its run.

I want to use inline nodejs in an aws lambda function, so no free tier postgres.  I want to stay within the aws framework, so no http api access to free personal cloud storage.  I'm guessing a single s3 file is my best bet, even aurora serverless has lag time to spin back up, and will charge for storage.  Are there any other options for persisting this string between runs of a lambda function?  Some sort of aws caching mechanism, hopefully accessible with their aws-sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamoDB is a perfect fit for what you described.

Comment: Dunno what the hell is up with the downvotes or locking, this is exactly what i was looking for, thanks

Comment: @user433342 software recommendations are off topic.